# how to install a package into anaconda environment via pip (windows)

Tags: python, anaconda

I am trying to install a python package called 'pyautocad,' which can be downloaded [here](https://pyautocad.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gettingstarted.html#installation).

According to the website, all I need is to type `pip install --upgrade pyautocad`in cmd.

By typing  `pip list`, I was able to see that 'pyautocad' is indeed installed.

I understand that installing packages by pip is not going to install packages into my Anaconda environment naturally.

Is there a way I can have a python package installed via pip show up in the base environment of Anaconda?

Comment: Have you activated your conda environment before trying to run the pip comamnd? Once you have done this, you should be able to install pip packages as per normal into that environment